# How to review dismissed warning messages in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssas, sql-server-data-tools, dismiss

In Visual Studio 2012 t(particulary in Data Tools for SSAS) there's an option to Dismiss Warning messages from the Error Log. You can even add a comment before dismissing individual warning.

Question: How can I review (and/or undo) warnings that were dismissed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677343%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), you can review them by completing the following steps:

1) Right-click the project in Solution Explorer, click Edit Database, then click the Warnings Tab.

2) View the Dismissed Warnings Grid

There is a Re-Enable option there

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

1. Select Menu / Database / View / Warnings.
2. Go to the "Dismissed Warnings" list.
3. Uncheck all the previously-dismissed warnings that you want to re-enable.
4. Click on Close (or Ctrl + F4)
5. Done!

Hope it helps! If not, drop me a line.